# How to set the part of the text view is clickable

Tags: android, string, textview, clickablespan

I have the text "**Android is a Software stack**". In this text i want to set the "**stack**" text as clickable. So, if you click on that it will redirected to a new activity(not in the browser).

I tried but i am not getting a solution.

Comment: "I tried but i am not getting"  I would like to know what you tried and where you failed

Answer (score 644, accepted):

`android.text.style.ClickableSpan` can solve your problem.

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Android is a Software stack");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
};
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 22, 27, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

*In XML:*

```
<TextView 
  ...
  android:textColorLink="@drawable/your_selector"
/>
```

Comment: Can u set multiple ClickableSpan objects in a textview?

Comment: Yes you can set several clickable spans to spanable string.

Comment: To get  the colour to change to blue, you could add: 
```ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);
                ss.setSpan(fcs, 22, 27, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);```

Comment: This happened in my case, to change colour from blue to some other. Set `ForegroundColorSpan` in `setSpan` **after** you have set the clickable span. Placing Foreground before Clickable span, new color won't be reflected.

Comment: thanks for this line stextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: Is there a way to define the range of the clickable span in XML? I have my strings defined there and I'd like the range to be specified there.

Comment: With @ShubhamA. changes, I also had two links within the text, so I had to new up two separate instances of `ForegroundColorSpan` in order for the change to take effect.

Comment: @xemacobra in the above example if you add fcs as the first parameter instead of clickablespan, where will clickable span go?

Comment: This works for me. Besides, as a suppliment, you need call 
 textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstanve()); for your text view.

Comment: To use with Xamarin see https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15310/how-to-use-clickable-span

Comment: How about when using binding? The textview's text is binded to a string inside the ViewModel, then how to make part of the text clickable? I actually have a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521741/in-android-if-i-use-binding-how-to-apply-clickablespan

Comment: It may have changed since you answered, but as of now you don't need the updateDrawState function.

Comment: you might need to add `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` , here the references : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641343/android-clickablespan-not-calling-onclick

Comment: `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` is required to make the click work.

Comment: To change the color without using ForegroundColorSpan you can change it directly in the updateDrawState() method by saying ds.setColor(yourColor)

Comment: Here, How to apply justification to this textview

Comment: @dira I have a similar use case, but need to click on only the hint of an EditText line, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74750234/android-launch-popupmenu-from-click-touch-only-on-the-hint-shown-on-an-edittext.  Any ideas on how to solve?

Answer (score 204):

My function for make multiple links inside `TextView`
**Update 2020:** Now this function able to support multiple same texts link inside 1 `TextView`, but remember to put the link in the correct order

```
fun TextView.makeLinks(vararg links: Pair<String, View.OnClickListener>) {
    val spannableString = SpannableString(this.text)
    var startIndexOfLink = -1
    for (link in links) {
        val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun updateDrawState(textPaint: TextPaint) {
                // use this to change the link color
                textPaint.color = textPaint.linkColor
                // toggle below value to enable/disable
                // the underline shown below the clickable text
                textPaint.isUnderlineText = true
            }

            override fun onClick(view: View) {
                Selection.setSelection((view as TextView).text as Spannable, 0)
                view.invalidate()
                link.second.onClick(view)
            }
        }
        startIndexOfLink = this.text.toString().indexOf(link.first, startIndexOfLink + 1)
//      if(startIndexOfLink == -1) continue // todo if you want to verify your texts contains links text
        spannableString.setSpan(
            clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + link.first.length,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
    }
    this.movementMethod =
        LinkMovementMethod.getInstance() // without LinkMovementMethod, link can not click
    this.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}
```

**USING**

```
my_text_view.makeLinks(
        Pair("Terms of Service", View.OnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Terms of Service Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }),
        Pair("Privacy Policy", View.OnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Privacy Policy Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }))
```

**XML**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please accept Terms of Service and Privacy Policy"
    android:textColorHighlight="#f00" // background color when pressed
    android:textColorLink="#0f0"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

**DEMO**

[image]

**Reference**

Solution for clear the link highlight selection follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/19445108/5381331

Comment: It is working perfectly. But there is something weird behavior is showing up. I have a text ending with "Policy." Where the "." will be skipped by Clickable spannable. Have anyone had the same issue?. The "." is only skipped if it is the end character of a text view.

Comment: great solution, but someone need to take care if have localisation(multiple language App) of strings

Comment: Thanks. It is working great. I wanna tell that if you are setting formatted string like
<string name="string">Something %1$s Edit</string>. 
Keep in mind first set whatever you want to in place of %1$s then call makeLinks method.

Comment: can you please tell how can I use this function because when I am just pasting your in onCreate method it shows error.

Comment: @BlackBlind which error you get? if it is some error with import, please import it correctly. also you should not put function inside onCreate, put it outside

Comment: This was amazing. Just in case *something* changes in the string, I added a check to make sure it's there:`val existsInString : Boolean = this.text.toString().contains(link.first)`

Comment: Where should I set this function? I'm a newbie, sorry.

Comment: In case of duplicate links, it always returns the first one as this solution is using `indexOf`

Comment: i could not get the highlighting to stop showing, otherwise great solution!

Comment: Thanks! My java equivalent: https://gist.github.com/daler445/b7106b5c5ed431ecfb206afe98746bbe

Comment: @anshsachdeva if you want the highlight to not show when the link is clicked, you can add in "updateDrawState" this line "highlightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT".

Comment: @Linh I have a similar use case but need to click on only the hint of an EditText line, here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74750234/android-launch-popupmenu-from-click-touch-only-on-the-hint-shown-on-an-edittext.  Any ideas on how to solve?

Answer (score 42):

You can use [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982241/android-clickable-textview-how-to-make-multiple-click-regions-on-text-and-catch)

#### Sample code:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
String myString = "Some text [clickable]";
int i1 = myString.indexOf("[");
int i2 = myString.indexOf("]");
myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
myTextView.setText(myString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable mySpannable = (Spannable)myTextView.getText();
ClickableSpan myClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View widget) { /* do something */ }
};
mySpannable.setSpan(myClickableSpan, i1, i2 + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

[Reference](http://adilatwork.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-how-to-make-only-part-of.html)

Comment: thx @ImranRana, Upvoted for `startIndex` and `endIndex` logic.

Comment: using [] for calculate start index and end index , is the perfect way , but is also display [] in text . I don't want to display [] in text .

Comment: @Imran Rana I have a similar use case, but need to click on the hint of an EditText line, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74750234/android-launch-popupmenu-from-click-touch-only-on-the-hint-shown-on-an-edittext.  Any ideas on how to solve?

Answer (score 21):

I made this helper method in case someone need start and end position from a String.

```
public static TextView createLink(TextView targetTextView, String completeString,
    String partToClick, ClickableSpan clickableAction) {

    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(completeString);

    // make sure the String is exist, if it doesn't exist
    // it will throw IndexOutOfBoundException
    int startPosition = completeString.indexOf(partToClick);
    int endPosition = completeString.lastIndexOf(partToClick) + partToClick.length();

    spannableString.setSpan(clickableAction, startPosition, endPosition,
        Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    targetTextView.setText(spannableString);
    targetTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    return targetTextView;
}
```

And here is how you use it

```
private void initSignUp() {
    String completeString = "New to Reddit? Sign up here.";
    String partToClick = "Sign up";
    ClickableTextUtil
        .createLink(signUpEditText, completeString, partToClick,
            new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    // your action
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Start Sign up activity",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                    super.updateDrawState(ds);
                    // this is where you set link color, underline, typeface etc.
                    int linkColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.blumine);
                    ds.setColor(linkColor);
                    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: This is better as it takes in consideration localisation

Comment: @aldok I have a similar use case, but need to click on the hint of an EditText line, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74750234/android-launch-popupmenu-from-click-touch-only-on-the-hint-shown-on-an-edittext.  Any ideas on how to solve?

Answer (score 19):

You can use sample code. You want to learn detail about ClickableSpan. Please check **this [documentaion](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html)**

```
  SpannableString myString = new SpannableString("This is example");
            
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View textView) {
                        ToastUtil.show(getContext(),"Clicked Smile ");
                    }
                };
        
        //For Click
         myString.setSpan(clickableSpan,startIndex,lastIndex,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        
        //For UnderLine
         myString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),startIndex,lastIndex,0);
        
        //For Bold
        myString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),startIndex,lastIndex,0);
        
        //Finally you can set to textView. 
        
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpan);
        textView.setText(myString);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is a `Kotlin` method to make parts of a `TextView` clickable:

```
private fun makeTextLink(textView: TextView, str: String, underlined: Boolean, color: Int?, action: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
    val spannableString = SpannableString(textView.text)
    val textColor = color ?: textView.currentTextColor
    val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(textView: View) {
            action?.invoke()
        }
        override fun updateDrawState(drawState: TextPaint) {
            super.updateDrawState(drawState)
            drawState.isUnderlineText = underlined
            drawState.color = textColor
        }
    }
    val index = spannableString.indexOf(str)
    spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, index, index + str.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    textView.text = spannableString
    textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    textView.highlightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
}
```

It can be called multiple times to create several links within a TextView:

```
makeTextLink(myTextView, str, false, Color.RED, action = { Log.d("onClick", "link") })
makeTextLink(myTextView, str1, true, null, action = { Log.d("onClick", "link1") })
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PP1);

 t.setText(Html.fromHtml("<bThis is normal text </b>" +
                "<a href=\"http://www.xyz-zyyx.com\">This is cliclable text</a> "));
 t.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer. Answer with explanations are always better. I also edited as your code snippet was not all in the right format.

Comment: Looks like the link would be to a web page, not to an activity as the OP requested.

Comment: This is for an hyperlink and not for an activity. Could a similar method be used for activities/fragments?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest a different approach that I think requires less code and is more "localization-friendly".

Supposing that your destination activity is called "ActivityStack", define in the manifest an intent filter for it with a custom scheme (e.g. "myappscheme") in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityStack">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:host="stack"/>
        <data android:scheme="myappscheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Define the TextView without any special tag (it is important to NOT use the "android:autoLink" tag, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20647011/1699702):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stackView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stack_string" />
```

then use a link with custom scheme and host in the text of the TextView as (in String.xml):

```
<string name="stack_string">Android is a Software <a href="myappscheme://stack">stack</a></string>
```

and "activate" the link with setMovementMethod() (in onCreate() for activities or onCreateView() for fragments):

```
TextView stack = findViewById(R.id.stackView);
stack.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This will open the stack activity with a tap on the "stack" word.

Answer (score 4):

**Kotlin Version** of Phan Van Linh's answer.

*Please note it has some minor modifications.*

```
fun makeLinks(textView: TextView, links: Array<String>, clickableSpans: Array<ClickableSpan>) {
    val spannableString = SpannableString(textView.text)

    for (i in links.indices) {
        val clickableSpan = clickableSpans[i]
        val link = links[i]

        val startIndexOfLink = textView.text.indexOf(link)

        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + link.length,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }

    textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}

fun setupClickableTextView() {
    val termsOfServicesClick = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "ToS clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    val privacyPolicyClick = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "PP clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    makeLinks(termsTextView, arrayOf("terms", "privacy policy"), arrayOf(termsOfServicesClick, privacyPolicyClick))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can you this method to set the clickable value

```
public void setClickableString(String clickableValue, String wholeValue, TextView yourTextView){
    String value = wholeValue;
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(value);
    int startIndex = value.indexOf(clickableValue);
    int endIndex = startIndex + clickableValue.length();
    spannableString.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                                @Override
                                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                                    super.updateDrawState(ds);
                                    ds.setUnderlineText(false); // <-- this will remove automatic underline in set span
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View widget) {
                                    // do what you want with clickable value
                                }
                            }, startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    yourTextView.setText(spannableString);
    yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); // <-- important, onClick in ClickableSpan won't work without this
}
```

This is how to use it:

```
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
setClickableString("stack", "Android is a Software stack", myTextView);
```

Answer (score 3):

For those that are looking for a solution in **Kotlin** here is what worked for me:

```
private fun setupTermsAndConditions() {
    val termsAndConditions = resources.getString(R.string.terms_and_conditions)
    val spannableString = SpannableString(termsAndConditions)
    val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            if (checkForWifiAndMobileInternet()) {
                // binding.viewModel!!.openTermsAndConditions()
                showToast("Good, open the link!!!")

            } else {
                showToast("Cannot open this file because of internet connection!")
            }

        }

        override fun updateDrawState(textPaint : TextPaint) {
            super.updateDrawState(textPaint)
            textPaint.color = resources.getColor(R.color.colorGrey)
            textPaint.isFakeBoldText = true
        }
    }

    spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 34, 86, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    binding.tvTermsAndConditions.text = spannableString
    binding.tvTermsAndConditions.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    binding.tvTermsAndConditions.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Created elegant `Kotlin` way with extension:

```
fun TextView.setClickableText(text: Spanned,
                              clickableText: String,
                              @ColorInt clickableColor: Int,
                              clickListener: () -> Unit) {
    val spannableString = SpannableString(text)

    val startingPosition: Int = text.indexOf(clickableText)

    if (startingPosition > -1) {
        val clickableSpan: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(textView: View) {
                clickListener()
            }

            override fun updateDrawState(textPaint: TextPaint) {
                super.updateDrawState(textPaint)
                textPaint.isUnderlineText = false
            }
        }

        val endingPosition: Int = startingPosition + clickableText.length
        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, startingPosition,
                endingPosition, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(clickableColor), startingPosition,
                endingPosition, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        highlightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }

    setText(spannableString)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Boom Check this for java Lovers :D**
We can modify it according to our need:

```
List<Pair<String, View.OnClickListener>> pairsList = new ArrayList<>();

        pairsList.add(new Pair<>("38,50", v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("which", "tos");
            startActivity(intent);
        }));

        pairsList.add(new Pair<>("81,95", v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("which", "policy");
            startActivity(intent);
        }));

        makeLinks(pairsList); // Method calling


private void makeLinks(List<Pair<String, View.OnClickListener>> pairsList) {

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(By signing up, I’m agree to PAKRISM’s Terms of Use and confirms that I have read Privacy Policy);

        for (Pair<String, View.OnClickListener> pair : pairsList) {

            ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View textView) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pair.second.onClick(textView);
                }

                @Override
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {

                    ds.linkColor = ContextCompat.getColor(SignUpActivity.this, R.color.primary_main);
                    ds.setUnderlineText(true);

                    super.updateDrawState(ds);
                }
            };

            String[] indexes = pair.first.split(",");
            ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, Integer.parseInt(indexes[0]), Integer.parseInt(indexes[1]), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        tv.setText(ss);
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For kotlin use this extension

```
fun TextView.makeLinks(vararg links: Pair<String, View.OnClickListener>) {
val spannableString = SpannableString(this.text)

for (link in links) {
    val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(view: View) {
            Selection.setSelection((view as TextView).text as Spannable, 0)
            view.invalidate()
            link.second.onClick(view)
        }
    }

    val startIndexOfLink = this.text.toString().indexOf(link.first)
    spannableString.setSpan(
        clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + link.first.length,
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )

    spannableString.setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#46C2CC")),
        startIndexOfLink,
        startIndexOfLink + link.first.length,
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
}

this.movementMethod =
    LinkMovementMethod.getInstance() // without LinkMovementMethod, link can not click
this.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}
```

Call this like this

```
binding.agreeText.makeLinks(Pair(getString(R.string.terms_conditionsClick),View.OnClickListener {
        startActivity(TermsAndConditionActivity.getIntent(this))
    }))
```

Answer (score 1):

For bold,

```
mySpannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),termStart,termStop,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 1):

i coded an example to solve your question in Kotlin.

This is the Code:

```
    val completeText = getString(R.string.terms_description)
    val textToFind = getString(R.string.show_terms)
    val spannableString: Spannable = SpannableString(completeText)
    val startFocus = completeText.indexOf(textToFind)
    val endFocus = startFocus + textToFind.length

    spannableString.setSpan(object: ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(p0: View) {
            showMessage()
        }
    }, startFocus, endFocus, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    show_terms.text = spannableString
    show_terms.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance();
    show_terms.highlightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT;
```

This is the XML

```
    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_agree_terms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_terms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/check_agree_terms"/>
```

This is how it looks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8lHF.png)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using URLSpan class to get urls

```
val spans: Array<URLSpan> = result.getSpans(0, result.length, URLSpan::class.java)
```

#### Method

```
fun TextView.createClickable(string: String, action:(String)->Unit ) {
      text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(string, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
      val result = SpannableString(text)
      val spans = result.getSpans(0, result.length, URLSpan::class.java)
      for (span in spans) {
          val link:Pair<String, View.OnClickListener> = Pair(span.url, View.OnClickListener {
              action(span.url)
          })
          val start = result.getSpanStart(span)
          val end = result.getSpanEnd(span)
          val flags = result.getSpanFlags(span)
          result.removeSpan(span)
          val clickableSpan: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
              override fun onClick(textView: View) {
                  textView.invalidate()
                  link.second.onClick(textView)
              }
              override fun updateDrawState(textPaint: TextPaint) {
                  super.updateDrawState(textPaint)
                  textPaint.isUnderlineText = false
              }
          }
          result.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, flags)
          this.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
          this.setText(result, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
      }
  }
```

#### Use

Example Text : **Android is a Software Stack and it' Awesome**

Wrapper your clickable text inside anchor tag

Like: `Android is a Software <a href='https://example.com/stack'> Stack </a> and it' <a href='https://example.com/awesome'> Awesome </a>.`

```
 val str = "Android is a Software <a href='https://example.com/stack'> Stack </a> and it' <a href='https://example.com/awesome'> Awesome </a>."

textView.createClickable(str) {
    when(it) {
        "https://example.com/stack"->{
  startActivity(Intent(this,StackActivity::class.java))
                  }
        "https://example.com/awesom"->{
            startActivity(Intent(this,AwesomeActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a Kotlin solution that work better with localization:

```
data class LinkedText(@StringRes val textRes: Int, val clickListener: View.OnClickListener? = null)

fun TextView.setPartiallyLinkedText(vararg texts: LinkedText) {
    this.text = texts.joinToString(" ") { context.getString(it.textRes) }
    val spannableString = SpannableString(this.text)
    var startIndexOfLink = -1
    texts.forEach { text ->
        val string = context.getString(text.textRes)
        if (text.clickListener != null) {
            val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
                override fun updateDrawState(textPaint: TextPaint) {
                    textPaint.color = textPaint.linkColor
                    textPaint.isUnderlineText = true
                }
                override fun onClick(view: View) {
                    Selection.setSelection((view as TextView).text as Spannable, 0)
                    view.invalidate()
                    text.clickListener.onClick(view)
                }
            }
            startIndexOfLink = this.text.toString().indexOf(string, startIndexOfLink + 1)
            spannableString.setSpan(
                clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + string.length,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }
    }
    this.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    this.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}
```

And use it like this:

```
textView.setPartiallyLinkedText(
    LinkedText(R.string.not_linked_text),
    LinkedText(R.string.linked_text) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a kotlin extension (not works if text repeats)

```
textView.makeTextClickable(
    contentText = "Hello world",
    clickableText = "world",
    isBoldText = true,
    onClick = {
        openPageInBrowser(BuildConfig.PRIVACY_POLICY_URL)
    }
)



   internal fun TextView.makeTextClickable(
    contentText: String,
    clickableText: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    isUnderlineText: Boolean = false,
    isBoldText: Boolean = false
) {
    val spannableString = SpannableString(contentText)

    val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            onClick()
        }

        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds)
            ds.isUnderlineText = isUnderlineText
            ds.isFakeBoldText = isBoldText
        }
    }

    val clickableTextStartIndex = text.indexOf(clickableText)
    val clickableTextEndIndex = clickableTextStartIndex + clickableText.length

    spannableString.setSpan(
        clickableSpan,
        clickableTextStartIndex,
        clickableTextEndIndex,
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )

    this.text = spannableString
    this.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my `MovementMethod` for detecting link/text/image clicks. It is modified `LinkMovementMethod`.

```
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.NoCopySpan;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.text.style.URLSpan;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ClickMovementMethod extends ScrollingMovementMethod {
private Object FROM_BELOW = new NoCopySpan.Concrete();

private static final int CLICK = 1;
private static final int UP = 2;
private static final int DOWN = 3;

private Listener listener;

public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean canSelectArbitrarily() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean handleMovementKey(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, int keyCode,
                                    int movementMetaState, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            if (KeyEvent.metaStateHasNoModifiers(movementMetaState)) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                        event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && action(CLICK, widget, buffer)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.handleMovementKey(widget, buffer, keyCode, movementMetaState, event);
}

@Override
protected boolean up(TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
    if (action(UP, widget, buffer)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.up(widget, buffer);
}

@Override
protected boolean down(TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
    if (action(DOWN, widget, buffer)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.down(widget, buffer);
}

@Override
protected boolean left(TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
    if (action(UP, widget, buffer)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.left(widget, buffer);
}

@Override
protected boolean right(TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
    if (action(DOWN, widget, buffer)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.right(widget, buffer);
}

private boolean action(int what, TextView widget, Spannable buffer) {
    Layout layout = widget.getLayout();

    int padding = widget.getTotalPaddingTop() +
            widget.getTotalPaddingBottom();
    int areatop = widget.getScrollY();
    int areabot = areatop + widget.getHeight() - padding;

    int linetop = layout.getLineForVertical(areatop);
    int linebot = layout.getLineForVertical(areabot);

    int first = layout.getLineStart(linetop);
    int last = layout.getLineEnd(linebot);

    ClickableSpan[] candidates = buffer.getSpans(first, last, URLSpan.class);

    int a = Selection.getSelectionStart(buffer);
    int b = Selection.getSelectionEnd(buffer);

    int selStart = Math.min(a, b);
    int selEnd = Math.max(a, b);

    if (selStart < 0) {
        if (buffer.getSpanStart(FROM_BELOW) >= 0) {
            selStart = selEnd = buffer.length();
        }
    }

    if (selStart > last)
        selStart = selEnd = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (selEnd < first)
        selStart = selEnd = -1;

    switch (what) {
        case CLICK:
            if (selStart == selEnd) {
                return false;
            }

            if (listener != null) {
                URLSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(selStart, selEnd, URLSpan.class);
                if (link.length >= 1) {
                    listener.onClick(link[0].getURL());
                } else {
                    ImageSpan[] image = buffer.getSpans(selStart, selEnd, ImageSpan.class);
                    if (image.length >= 1) {
                        listener.onImageClicked(image[0].getSource());
                    } else {
                        listener.onTextClicked();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case UP:
            int beststart, bestend;

            beststart = -1;
            bestend = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
                int end = buffer.getSpanEnd(candidates[i]);

                if (end < selEnd || selStart == selEnd) {
                    if (end > bestend) {
                        beststart = buffer.getSpanStart(candidates[i]);
                        bestend = end;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (beststart >= 0) {
                Selection.setSelection(buffer, bestend, beststart);
                return true;
            }

            break;

        case DOWN:
            beststart = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            bestend = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
                int start = buffer.getSpanStart(candidates[i]);

                if (start > selStart || selStart == selEnd) {
                    if (start < beststart) {
                        beststart = start;
                        bestend = buffer.getSpanEnd(candidates[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (bestend < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                Selection.setSelection(buffer, beststart, bestend);
                return true;
            }

            break;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer,
                            MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
            action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
        y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

        x += widget.getScrollX();
        y += widget.getScrollY();

        Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
        int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

        URLSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off, URLSpan.class);

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (listener != null) {
                if (link.length >= 1) {
                    listener.onClick(link[0].getURL());
                } else {
                    ImageSpan[] image = buffer.getSpans(off, off, ImageSpan.class);
                    if (image.length >= 1) {
                        listener.onImageClicked(image[0].getSource());
                    } else if (Selection.getSelectionStart(buffer) == Selection.getSelectionEnd(buffer)) {
                        listener.onTextClicked();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && link.length != 0) {
            Selection.setSelection(buffer,
                    buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]),
                    buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
            return true;
        }

        if (link.length == 0) {
            Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
        }
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
}

@Override
public void initialize(TextView widget, Spannable text) {
    Selection.removeSelection(text);
    text.removeSpan(FROM_BELOW);
}

@Override
public void onTakeFocus(TextView view, Spannable text, int dir) {
    Selection.removeSelection(text);

    if ((dir & View.FOCUS_BACKWARD) != 0) {
        text.setSpan(FROM_BELOW, 0, 0, Spannable.SPAN_POINT_POINT);
    } else {
        text.removeSpan(FROM_BELOW);
    }
}

public interface Listener {

    void onClick(String clicked);

    void onTextClicked();

    void onImageClicked(String source);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

more generic answer in kotlin

```
   fun setClickableText(view: TextView, firstSpan: String, secondSpan: String) {
    val context = view.context
    val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()
    val unClickableSpan = SpannableString(firstSpan)
    val span = SpannableString(" "+secondSpan)

    builder.append(unClickableSpan);
    val clickableSpan: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(textView: View) {
            val intent = Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java)
         context.startActivity(intent)
        }

        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds)
            ds.isUnderlineText = true
            ds.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.ITALIC));
        }
    }
    builder.append(span);
    builder.setSpan(clickableSpan, firstSpan.length, firstSpan.length+secondSpan.length+1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

    view.setText(builder,TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
    view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided are pretty decent. However, I generally use a more simple solution.

Here is a linkify utility function

```
/**
 * Method is used to Linkify words in a TextView
 *
 * @param textView TextView who's text you want to change
 * @param textToLink The text to turn into a link
 * @param url   The url you want to send the user to
 */
fun linkify(textView: TextView, textToLink: String, url: String) {
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(textToLink)
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, pattern, url, { _, _, _ -> true })
    { _, _ -> "" }
}
```

Using this function is pretty simple. Here is an example

```
    // terms and privacy
    val tvTerms = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_terms)
    val tvPrivacy = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_privacy)
    Utils.linkify(tvTerms, resources.getString(R.string.terms),
            Constants.TERMS_URL)
    Utils.linkify(tvPrivacy, resources.getString(R.string.privacy),
            Constants.PRIVACY_URL)
```

Comment: I have a similar use case, but need to click on the hint of an EditText line, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74750234/android-launch-popupmenu-from-click-touch-only-on-the-hint-shown-on-an-edittext.  Any ideas on how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Complicated but universal solution on Kotlin

```
  /*
    * Receive Pair of Text and Action and set it clickable and appearing as link
    * */
fun TextView.setClickableText(vararg textToSpanAndClickAction: Pair<String, (String) -> Unit>) {
    val builder = SpannableStringBuilder(text.toString())

    textToSpanAndClickAction.forEach { argPair ->
    val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            argPair.second.invoke(argPair.first)
        }
    }

    this.text.toString().let { fullText ->
        val indexOfFirst = fullText.indexOf(argPair.first)
        val indexOfLast = indexOfFirst + argPair.first.length
        if (indexOfFirst < 0){
            //No match found
            return
        }else{
            builder.setSpan(
                clickableSpan,
                indexOfFirst,
                indexOfLast,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }
    }
}

this.text = builder
    this.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
}
```

[kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) [spannable](/questions/tagged/spannable)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in Java (Updated 2022)**

Features:

- Allows for multiple clickable when there are repeated words.
- Specific commands can be tailored for each repeated words.

I built upon daler445's code to allow for multiple clickable commands for repeated words.

**At Java class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sp = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

        TextView fulltext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fulltext);

        //replace setText("") to setText("Android is a Software stack") for his case
        fulltext.setText("Search [1] this full [1] text with repeated strings. Search [2] Search [3] full [2] full [3]");

        List<Pair<String, View.OnClickListener>> links = new ArrayList<>();

        //replace "Search" with "stack" for his case
        String stringtohyperlink = "Search";
        String stringtohyperlink2 = "full";

        links.add(new Pair<>(stringtohyperlink, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String position = sp.getString("position","0");
                if (position.equals("1")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search 1 has been Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editor.putString("position","0");
                    editor.apply();
                }
                if (position.equals("2")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search 2 has been Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editor.putString("position","0");
                    editor.apply();
                }
                if (position.equals("3")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search 3 has been Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editor.putString("position","0");
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        }));

        links.add(new Pair<>(stringtohyperlink2, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String position = sp.getString("position","0");
                if (position.equals("1")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "full 1 has been Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editor.putString("position","0");
                    editor.apply();
                }
                if (position.equals("2")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "full 2 has been Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editor.putString("position","0");
                    editor.apply();
                }
                if (position.equals("3")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "full 3 has been Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editor.putString("position","0");
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        }));


        makeLinks(fulltext, links);


    }

    public void makeLinks(TextView textView, List<Pair<String, View.OnClickListener>> links) {
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(textView.getText().toString());

        int startIndexState = -1;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

        for (Pair<String, View.OnClickListener> link : links) {
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                    editor.putString("position","1");
                    editor.apply();

                    widget.invalidate();
                    assert link.second != null;
                    link.second.onClick(widget);
                }
            };
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan2 = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                    editor.putString("position","2");
                    editor.apply();

                    widget.invalidate();
                    assert link.second != null;
                    link.second.onClick(widget);
                }
            };

            ClickableSpan clickableSpan3 = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                    editor.putString("position","3");
                    editor.apply();

                    widget.invalidate();
                    assert link.second != null;
                    link.second.onClick(widget);
                }
            };
            //... This only allows for 3 repeated words
            //... Add more of it, if there are more repeated words.

            assert link.first != null;
            int startIndexOfLink = textView.getText().toString().indexOf(link.first, startIndexState + 1);
            spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + link.first.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

            int startIndexOfLink2 = textView.getText().toString().indexOf(link.first, startIndexOfLink + 1);
            if (startIndexOfLink2 != -1) {
                spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan2, startIndexOfLink2, startIndexOfLink2 + link.first.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            }

            int startIndexOfLink3 = textView.getText().toString().indexOf(link.first, startIndexOfLink2 + 1);
            if (startIndexOfLink3 != -1) {
                spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan3, startIndexOfLink3, startIndexOfLink3 + link.first.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            }
            //... This only allows for 3 repeated words
            //... Add more of it, if there are more repeated words.

            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

**At .xml**

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fulltext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Demo**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin using extension buildSpannedString, which seems to be the fastest approach

```
textView.apply {
    movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    text = buildSpannedString {
        append("Android is a Software ")
        inSpans(
            span = setOnClickListener {
                       startActivity(YourActivity)
                   },
            builderAction = {
                append("stack")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

You can use this `extension function`.

```
fun TextView.clickSpan(
        str: String, range: IntRange,
        color: Int = Color.RED, isUnderlineText: Boolean = false, clickListener: View.OnClickListener
) {
    movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    highlightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT  // remove click bg color
    text = str.toClickSpan(range, color, isUnderlineText, clickListener)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It really helpful for the clickable part for some portion of the text.

The dot is a special character in the regular expression. If you want to spanable the dot need to escape dot as `\\`. instead of just passing "`.`" to the spanable text method. Alternatively, you can also use the regular expression `[.]` to spanable the String by a dot in Java.