# Continue reading like facebook in textview inside Listview

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have followed

[Set Text View ellipsize and add view more at end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099296/set-text-view-ellipsize-and-add-view-more-at-end)

and added the view more and view less in the listview item.But the problem starts on scrolling, view more sometimes vanishes and all the text view get expanded automatically.How can I fix this, please help.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null) inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
    TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
    TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
    NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);
    FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);
    name.setText(item.getName());
    CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()), System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    timestamp.setText(timeAgo);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
       ////This is TextView I want to expand
        statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        makeTextViewResizable(statusMsg, 3, "...More", true);
    } else {
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (item.getUrl() != null) {
        url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));
        url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // user profile pic
    profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

    // Feed image
    if (item.getImge() != null) {
        feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        feedImageView
                .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }
                });
    } else {
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

public static void makeTextViewResizable(final TextView tv, final int maxLine, final String expandText, final boolean viewMore) {
    if (tv.getTag() == null) {
        tv.setTag(tv.getText());
    }
    ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            if (maxLine == 0) {
                int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
                String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - expandText.length() + 1) + " " + expandText;
                tv.setText(text);
                tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                tv.setText(addClickablePartTextViewResizable(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()), tv, maxLine, expandText, viewMore), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else if (maxLine > 0 && tv.getLineCount() >= maxLine) {
                int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(maxLine - 1);
                String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - expandText.length() + 1) + " " + expandText;
                tv.setText(text);
                tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                tv.setText(addClickablePartTextViewResizable(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()), tv, maxLine, expandText, viewMore), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(tv.getLayout().getLineCount() - 1);
                String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex) + " " + expandText;
                tv.setText(text);
                tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                tv.setText(addClickablePartTextViewResizable(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()), tv, lineEndIndex, expandText, viewMore), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    });
}

private static SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePartTextViewResizable(final Spanned strSpanned, final TextView tv, final int maxLine, final String spanableText, final boolean viewMore) {
    String str = strSpanned.toString();
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(strSpanned);
    if (str.contains(spanableText)) {
        ssb.setSpan(new MySpannable(false) {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                if (viewMore) {
                    tv.setLayoutParams(tv.getLayoutParams());
                    tv.setText(tv.getTag().toString(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                    tv.invalidate();
                    makeTextViewResizable(tv, -1, "...Less", false);
                } else {
                    tv.setLayoutParams(tv.getLayoutParams());
                    tv.setText(tv.getTag().toString(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                    tv.invalidate();
                    makeTextViewResizable(tv, 3, "...More", true);
                }
            }
        }, str.indexOf(spanableText), str.indexOf(spanableText) + spanableText.length(), 0);
    }
    return ssb;
}
```

Comment: I think that you don't reset a state of the view (expanded) in your adapter for each new item

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: that depends on your adapter's `getView` method code.

Comment: I have posted the full getView method can you please add few lines where I will have reset the state.

Comment: No new Items have been added to the list.the problem is happening on scrolling of the listview

Comment: Add one boolean variable in your FeedItem (say, isExpanded). Then you can set item.isExpanded as true/false when clicked viewMore / viewLess. On scrolling just check & then show the textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution will add View More option if text length is greater than 150 and will ellipsize the text to 150 characters.On clicking on View More it will show complete text with Show Less option and on clicking on Show Less again it will ellipsize the text to 150 characters.It works well with recyclerview item's textview and should work with listview also.

```
if(inputText.length()>150)
        {
            String text=inputText.substring(0,150)+"...";
            final String fulltext=inputText;

            final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text+"View More");

            ClickableSpan span1 = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View textView) {
                    // do some thing
                    SpannableString ss1 = new SpannableString(fulltext+"Show Less");
                    ClickableSpan span2 = new ClickableSpan() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View textView) {
                            // do some thing
                            textView.setText(ss);
                            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

                        }
                    };
                    ss1.setSpan(span2, fulltext.length(), ss1.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), fulltext.length(), ss1.length(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);


                    textView.setText(ss1);
                    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                }
            };
            ss.setSpan(span1, 153, 162, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 153,162,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setText(ss);
            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
else
        {
            textView.setText(inputText);
        }
```