# Add "View More" at the end of textview after 3 lines and show full text in dialog (pop up)

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I want to add "..more" at end of 3rd line for textview and if we click on more we will show full text in pop up (or custom dialog). So I used below code for this functionality. The code is working fine when you are in portrait mode but when you change device orientation it's not working. And I am using BaseAdapter and RecyclerView (by using ViewHelper design pattern).

```
public interface ViewMoreClickListener {
  void viewMoreClicked(int index);
}

public void addViewMoreToTextView(final int position, final TextView tv, final String expandText, final int maxLine, final ViewMoreClickListener listener) {
    try {
        if (tv.getTag() == null) {
            tv.setTag(tv.getText());
        }

        ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();

        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                String text = tv.getText().toString();

                if (tv.getLineCount() > maxLine) {
                    int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(maxLine - 1);
                    text = text.subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - expandText.length() + 1) + " " + expandText;
                    tv.setText(text);

                    // We are rechecking in order to resolve issue with alignment problem
                    if (tv.getLineCount() > maxLine) {
                        lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(maxLine - 1);
                        text = text.subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - expandText.length() + 1) + " " + expandText;
                        tv.setText(text);
                    }

                    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

                    String str = Html.fromHtml(text).toString();
                    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(Html.fromHtml(text));

                    if (str.contains(expandText)) {
                        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View widget) {
                                if (listener != null)
                                    listener.viewMoreClicked(position);
                            }
                        }, str.indexOf(expandText), str.indexOf(expandText) + expandText.length(), 0);
                    }

                    tv.setText(ssb);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class SampleActivity extends BaseActivity implements ViewMoreClickListener {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override
   public void viewMoreClicked(int index) {
       // here we will show full text in pop up or custom dialog by getting from arraylist based on index.
   }
}
```

And I am calling the above method from getView() of adapter.

```
addViewMoreToTextView(position, textview, "..more", 3, listener);
```

I have gone thorough these links but they also are not working in RecyclerView.

[Add "View More" at the end of textview after 3 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675331/add-view-more-at-the-end-of-textview-after-3-lines)

[Set Text View ellipsize and add view more at end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099296/set-text-view-ellipsize-and-add-view-more-at-end)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: have a look at [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667717/4168607). i think this is what you need .

Comment: @ADM Thank you for your response. I have gone through that link but there they are trimming text based on no. of characters but we need based on no. of lines. I think it will not fulfill my requirement. My code is not working only when we change orientation and in RecyclerView only.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using below code:

```
public void addViewMoreToTextView(final int position, final TextView textView, final String text, final String expandText, final int maxLine, final ViewMoreClickListener listener) {
    try {
        textView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SpannableStringBuilder truncatedSpannableString;
                int startIndex;

                if (textView.getLineCount() > maxLine) {
                    int lastCharShown = textView.getLayout().getLineVisibleEnd(maxLine - 1);
                    String displayText = text.substring(0, lastCharShown - expandText.length() + 1) + " " + expandText;
                    startIndex = displayText.indexOf(expandText);

                    truncatedSpannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder(displayText);

                    textView.setText(truncatedSpannableString);

                    truncatedSpannableString.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View widget) {
                            // this click event is not firing that's why we are adding click event for text view below.
                        }
                    }, startIndex, startIndex + expandText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    textView.setText(truncatedSpannableString);

                    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (listener != null)
                                listener.viewMoreClicked(position);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```