# Follow text gracefully within a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a LinearLayout as below.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Into this layout, dynamic TextViews are added at runtime. But before inserting at runtime I tried adding 5 texviews manually. This is how it looks like.

[image]

The layout for those textview is

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

I need the last text to gracefully follow normally rather than just breaking down as in the above image.

Where am I wrong? Could you help me figure this out?

**EDIT**

I have a message to display. For instance, **England** beats **Australia** in the **final championship**. Those bold texts have some ids attached which when clicked opens a dialog. So I break the text and add them as different TextViews so I could easly attach an onClickListener. I need the message to look one single text. Hope it makes more sense now.

**EDIT 2**

I used clickableSpan as a get around.

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(message);
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        Log.i(TAG_NAME, "clickable span...");
    }
};

spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 13, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 30, 40, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

All I am trying to do is add multiple span to a textview. However, it looks like only last span is working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by _"last text to gracefully follow normally"_? Should it go to the next line? Should it go out of the screen? Should all of them shrink to fit this one.. (what happens if there are more textviews than shown in picture..)?

Comment: You should not be having multiple text views. Use `ClickableSpan` instead. It will make your life easier.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10697453/827110 So basically, one textview which has `bold` parts that are `clickable`.. sounds good?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! so how do you identify which text is clicked? say when I click England. Clickable span works well for static texts. not sure about dynamic texts.

Comment: So each word, (England, Australia..) is a `ClickableSpan` which has its own `OnClickListener` so you will know

Comment: lemme play with it! keep you posted! Thanks for the comment

Comment: @Amulya Khare Can you check the Edit 2?

Comment: @Renjith: I think one span can only be added once. Try creating a second one...

Comment: @StackOverflowException yeah, that's the culprit! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give weight to each textView as 1

Try this:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Hope this works