# long press on selected text in textview in android

Tags: android, textview, long-press

In my android app, I have a text view and some text in it. I want that user can see the meaning of the words in a tool tip box when he long press on the word . My problem is that I don’t know how to implement long press in the words.Can some body help me?

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use following code:

```
tv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
});
```

and import:

```
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
```

if you want Click just for some part Of View you need `ClickableSpan`. copy code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable).

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Android is a Software stack");
    //ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 22, 27, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 22, 27, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: no , this method put long press on WHOLE the text view. I need long press just one the one word !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

use `setOnLongClickListener` instead of `OnClickListner`