# How to set multiple click event for the single textview?

Tags: android, string, dynamic, textview, clickablespan

I have a textview as like the following:

```
txtByRegistering.setText("By Registering you agree to terms and condition and privacy policy");
```

It is just a big text. So, I used marquee to scroll the text horizontally. that works fine. My Question is, How to invoke the click event while clicking the selected scrolling text .

Say for ex :

1. when user click the word ***"Registering"*** in the above textview, I have to invoke the new Intent.
2. When the user click on the word ***`"Terms"`*** , I have to
   invoke another new Intent (An Activity with webview as Terms has `URL Link`).

As the word "Registering" and "Terms" are Web URLs, I tried something like below :

```
    String mRegDesc = "By registering you agree to the " + "<a href=\""
            + Constant.URL + "/terms_and_conditions"
            + "\">Terms of Use</a> " + "and " + "<a href=\"" + Constant.URL
            + "/privacy" + "\">Privacy Policy</a> ";

    txtByRegistering.setText(Html.fromHtml(mRegDesc));
    txtByRegistering.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    txtByRegistering.setSelected(true);
    txtByRegistering.setTypeface(mTyFaceOverLockReg, Typeface.BOLD);
```

The above code works fine and it brings me to the browser when i click the word "Terms" But i wish to go to new Activity.

Comment: i think you need `ClickableSpan`, see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988905/long-press-on-selected-text-in-textview-in-android/20988922#20988922

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan Can i set multiple `ClickableSpan` for a Single `SpannableString`? Would you please more elaborate? And SpannableString supports the API level 8?

Comment: yes you can set multiple Clickabale on one String, and this method added on API level 1 for more info see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982241/android-clickable-textview-how-to-make-multiple-click-regions-on-text-and-catch

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally,

I found the solution for that,

Here is the solution :

```
    SpannableString SpanString = new SpannableString(
            "By Registering you agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy");

    ClickableSpan teremsAndCondition = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {


            Intent mIntent = new Intent(SignUp.this, CommonWebView.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("isTermsAndCondition", true);
            startActivity(mIntent);

        }
    };

   // Character starting from 32 - 45 is Terms and condition. 
   // Character starting from 49 - 63 is privacy policy. 

    ClickableSpan privacy = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {

            Intent mIntent = new Intent(SignUp.this, CommonWebView.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("isPrivacyPolicy", true);
            startActivity(mIntent);

        }
    };

    SpanString.setSpan(teremsAndCondition, 32, 45, 0);
    SpanString.setSpan(privacy, 49, 63, 0);
    SpanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 32, 45, 0);
    SpanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 49, 63, 0);
    SpanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 32, 45, 0);
    SpanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 49, 63, 0);

    txtByRegistering.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    txtByRegistering.setText(SpanString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    txtByRegistering.setSelected(true);
```

thanks to Shayan pourvatan.

Comment: any idea how to change underline color

Answer (score 2):

Let assume here is your complete string

**By Signing up, I agree to Terms of Conditions & Privacy Policy**

and string you want to make clickable is

**Terms of Conditions** and **Privacy Policy**

so, here is my trick.....

```
ClickableSpan terms = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        new Utils(getActivity()).shortToast("Terms");

    }
};

ClickableSpan privacy = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        new Utils(getActivity()).shortToast("Privacy");

    }
};
```

the main function for this

```
public void setClickableString(String wholeValue, TextView textView, final String[] clickableValue, ClickableSpan[] clickableSpans) {
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(wholeValue);

    for (int i = 0; i < clickableValue.length; i++) {
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = clickableSpans[i];
        String link = clickableValue[i];

        int startIndexOfLink = wholeValue.indexOf(link);
        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + link.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    textView.setHighlightColor(
            Color.TRANSPARENT); // prevent TextView change background when highlight
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

and here is the function calling

```
setClickableString(getString(R.string.terms_and_policy), tv_terms, new String[]{"Terms of Conditions", "Privacy Policy"}, new ClickableSpan[]{terms, privacy});
```

Comment: Marry me! *wink* *You the best*

Answer (score 0):

**Use this one it works for me two click in single TextView**

> Step1-: Your text will be in SpannableString

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("By Registering you agree to terms and condition and privacy policy");
```

> Step2:-add click in ClickableSpan like this

```
 ClickableSpan Registering = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,WebView_Activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(true);
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan terms = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(this,WebView_Activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(true);
        }
    };
```

> Final step add your click on SpannableString with character starting and ending index like Registering word in start at 3rd position and end at 11 so add click for Registering word

```
 ss.setSpan(Registering , 3, 11, 0);
```

> same for term after this add your SpannableString on your TextView

```
  textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textview.setText(ss, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    textview.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest below code for clickable string in `TextView` it is dynamic.
Advantage of this code is if you have same `String` multiple times you can have click on both `Strings`. For example if you want to set click and String is **`Boy` is playing cricket. `Boy` is playing football**. **`Boy`** is two times both word will be clickable.

```
    public void setClicksOnString(String completeString, List<String> stringsToClick, TextView textView) {
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(completeString);
        for (int m = 0; m < stringsToClick.size(); m++) {
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(stringsToClick.get(m)).matcher(spannableString);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                ClickableSpan stringClick = new ClickableSpan() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                        //you compare the string and your click logics

                    }
                };
                spannableString.setSpan(stringClick, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            }
        }
        textView.setHighlightColor(
                Color.TRANSPARENT); // prevent TextView change background when highlight
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you want to know in which text the user clicked dynamically, use below

```
 ClickableSpan listener = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) textView;
                Spanned s = (Spanned) tv.getText();
                int start = s.getSpanStart(this);
                int end = s.getSpanEnd(this);
                String clickedText = s.toString().substring(start,end);
            }
        };
```