# Android. How to set event click in a piece of text in TextView

Tags: android, textview, spannable

I have a string and i want to do like picture (Identify small pieces (like: [Am], [Em]) change color and assign events to it. And assign another event when i click on black text or any whitespace). Do you have any ideas? Help me please!

[image]

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. Add your code to the question. The clearer and more specific you are, the easier it will be to help.

Comment: [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22006998/2794507)