# How to override Android edittext double-touch selection bounds

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

When I double-touch (or long press) on the edittext widget it selects some text. The bounds of the selection seem to stop at whitespace. I would like to change this behaviour to stop at punctuation. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Please your question more.

Comment: i don't understand ur question. can u specify what u needed.

Comment: try some thing like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20988922

Comment: Looking over the source code it looks like its handled by the WordIterator. As best as I can tell the default one should be stopping at punctuation, but it doesn't seem to for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following:

```
txtInput.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int index = txtInput.getText().toString().indexOf("!");
                if(index!=-1){
                txtInput.setSelection(0, index);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is partially useful. How do you know where the long press occurs? It would be needed to work which subset of the selection to use. Also, this doesn't address the double tap case.