# Android set clickable text to go one fragment to another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, spannablestring

I need to do something like this. Suppose I have 2 fragments A and B.There is a text which can be clickable in fragment A and when user click this text , he can go to fragment B. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable) example helped me to do it but I think it does not work for fragment.  So please tell me a way to solve this problem.

```
public class myClaimsFragment extends Fragment {

   TextView requestNewClaim;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View newClaimRequest = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_claims, container, false);


        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Request");
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan , 0,ss.length() , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        requestNewClaim =(TextView) newClaimRequest.findViewById(R.id.requestHere);
        requestNewClaim.setText(ss.toString());
        requestNewClaim.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        return newClaimRequest;
    }

}
```

Layout XML

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/requestHere"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use `textview.setOnClickListener()` to do what you want to do.

Comment: I tried it.but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If LoginActivity is a fragment class then it would be okay if you use setOnClickListener on textview. But for fragment change you have to change Intent to fragmentTransaction,

Use something like,

```
textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new LoginActivity() ).addToBackStack("").commit();
});
```

But, if you want to use SpannableString then do like this,

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new LoginActivity() ).addToBackStack("").commit();
        }
    };
```

Here, R.id.container is the fragment of your main activity layout in which new view will be replaced.

Comment: Can you please tell me ,did I do any other mistake any where?I put this code inside the onClick() method. But there was nothing happen. I run this code and click on the text,but nothing happen.

Comment: no,But nothing happen. It gives a feeling like that I clicked on normal textView.Can you please tell me  that am I rightly set the TextView as clickable?:(

Comment: R u using SpannableString or just simple textView?

Comment: yeah, I was just keep checking for any other mistake! But its nice that, finally you are able to make it working. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not call Fragment via `Intent`. You need to replace your current fragment with new one.

Comment: _"You can not call Fragment via Intent..."_  I don't see any calling of fragments via `Intent`. The only `Intent` in OP's codes is for launching another activity that it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

you have to replace your fragment A to B, use this code

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment,fragment);
ft.commit();
```

In This code replace R.id.youframelayoutid, then it workable

If its code useful so please mark me my answer. :)

Comment: Can you please tell me ,did I do any other mistake any where?I put this code inside the onClick() method. But there was nothing happen. I run this code and click on the text,but nothing happen.

Comment: @Tangle :- in your code please find id of request here is first then on click functionality implement, i hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As an usual manner you should put a `FrameLayout` in your Activity's layout XML file. This FrameLayout acts like a placeholder for your Fragments. In other words, Fragment A can be pasted there, so is for Fragment B.

Okay, suppose you've added a `FrameLayout` in you activity's layout file. Pasting fragments on it and also replacing fragments should be done by the `FragmentManager`. Hence, you should grab a reference to a `FragmentManger` in your activity class. For getting this done ...

- If you use Android Support Libraries, you should get a reference to FragmentManger by `getSupportFragmentManager()`
- Otherwise, `getFragmentManager()`

In Android adding fragments and also replacing them are done in the form of a transaction. Thus you should inform the fragment manager that you would like to do a transaction. This could be done via:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManger.beginTransaction();
```

Now, you can apply all what you want on this transaction object. For instance, Adding a fragment could be done like this:

```
transaction.add(R.id.placeholder, new FragmentA() , "tag-frag-A");
```

For replacing ...

```
transaction.replace(R.id.placeholder, new FragmentB(), "tag-frag-B");
```

After you're done, you commit that transaction by calling

```
transaction.commit();
```

---

**Notes:**

- FragmentManager acts like a container for your added fragments. You can search through your added fragments by their tag.
- Device rotation does not remove added fragments in the FragmentManager. Thus in your `onCreate` method take care you've added any fragments only once.
- You can add a Transaction to the back stack. This means that whenever user clicks on the Android back button this fragment will be removed from the state stack and also will be rolled back.

Comment: Can you please tell me ,did I do any other mistake any where?I put this code inside the onClick() method. But there was nothing happen. I run this code and click on the text,but nothing happen.