# Android TextView Underline Keyword

Tags: java, android, textview, clickable

Is it possible to have TextView like this?

> Why Doesn’t McDonald Sell **Hotdogs**?

In above question, Hotdogs will be in red color or underlined, when the user clicks on Hotdogs, it will show another dialog or popup view explaining what is Hotdogs.

Is it possible to do or any hints how may I accomplish it ?

Comment: `TextView` can handle [`SpannableString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html). That's probably what you are looking for, although there's little documentatioin on their usage

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.  Please edit your post and share what you have tried so far.

Comment: To David Medenjak, that's what I'm looking for, thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable

Comment: How do I accept an answer?

Comment: You have to click on the grey checkbox [next to the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/261299).

Comment: I would like to give the credit to David Medenjak because he is the first one provide the correct solution. How may I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

Quoting from the Android reference

> This is the class for text whose content is immutable but to which markup objects can be attached and detached. For mutable text, see SpannableStringBuilder.