# Make phoneNumber from String resource clickable in dialog

Tags: android, html

I have a `string resource`:

```
<string name="dialog"> text + 800-800-800 + text</string>
```

`800-800-800` - is the phone number

I use this `string` in my `Dialog`:

The question is: how to make phone number clickable and `onClick` dial this number and call from the phone ?

I know how to make `hyperlink` using html `<a href="">` tag, make `TextView` clickable and `setMovementMethod()` and navigate to website from the `textview` but there is another case, I need behavior such as it is `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`.
My idea is make from my `string` 3 different strings, and for middle `string` with phone number set `Onclick` listener, but I think it`s work-around, maybe there is better way how to answer to my question?

Hope, I clearly explain my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ClickableSpan to make a String Clickable with onClick

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html

Solution is explained on this page:
[How to set the part of the text view is clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable)

Good luck!