# how to convert a text field to a link

Tags: java, android

In .xml file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sgn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:text="Sign Up"**>
</TextView>
```

Comment: Do you want to show a underline for this text view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a textview text link clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349822/how-to-make-a-textview-text-link-clickable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sgn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , RegisterActivity2.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: This Answer is not related to the question he asked about the link which refers to the weblink, not to another activity or screen of an android app