# basic for android - Equivalent of Span classes in b4a

Tags: android, vb4android

I  want to set part of my textview to be clickable with basic for android. how can I do that?
Documents are low. I am new in b4a and I can not handle myself in it yet

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable) maybe help.you should study some knowledge about span.

Comment: thank you Paul but what about b4a?

Comment: What do you mean by part of your textview to be clickable? Do you mean textbox? You should use the designer in B4A to customise the properties and layout of your elements.

Comment: Do you still require an answer? If so, I can write up something that will help you...