# Android gather info from http link before opening browser

Tags: java, android, http, hyperlink, listener

I have an HTTP link in my layout: `<string name="contact_us">Please <a href="mailto:SERVICES@some.com">email services</a> or call <a href="tel:4399999999">(408) 888-5555</a> for questions.</string>`

And in my activity:

```
disclaimer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disclaimer);    
disclaimer.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This works by opening a browser or the dial. But now I want to track some statistics before opening the links. Is there a way to "Listen" when this links are clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this kind of task using SpannableString.. please check this below code :

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Android is a Software stack");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
};
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 22, 27, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

It will work for you. and please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable) example.