# Can't transform html hyperlink from string resource

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a `hyperlink` from a `string` resource into a `TextView`.
I can't make the `HTML` code work and I feel I'm loosing control.

Before I continue I must say that I tried so many stuff but none of them worked.

My `String` in resource file is:

```
<string name="summary_terms_message">By pressing Send order, you agree with our <![CDATA[ &lt;a href=\"https://someurl.com\">terms and conditions&lt;/a>]]></string>
```

In activity I do the following:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.myString)));

textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and my textView looks like this:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/anotherTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/anotherTextView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:font="roboto_regular"
            android:text="@string/myString"
            android:textColor="@color/white_opacity_70" />
```

It is displayed the full text with escaped characters and everything but is not making the hyperlink.

Comment: Why dont you use "Spannable" for making hyperlink. Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable

Comment: Try this    `<string name="summary_terms_message">By pressing Send order, you agree with our <a href="https://someurl.com">terms and conditions</a> </string>`

Comment: Thank you @RahulGupta it actually worked