# How to add textview dynamically with clickable each item like in image?

Tags: android

Hi i want to create a list of textview with each item clickable like in the image.

[image]

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697453/3319074

Comment: @ZeroOne is right you can use SpannableString. Using that you can add multiple clickable span in your TextView as per you need

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick or in the Event you want to add a TextView try this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(Activity.this);
textView.setText();
textView.setTextColor();
textView.setTextSize();
textView.setOnClickListener();
```

Now suppose you have a horizontal LinearLayout then

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//Set your margins here.
params.topMargin = 0;
params.rightMargin = 0;
params.leftMargin = 0;
params.bottomMargin = 0;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Hope this helps.