# Extract phone number from TextView text

Tags: android, textview, linkify, autolink

I have a TextView with following words:

> Google LLC is an 123 American multinational technology 456 company that specializes in Internet-related services and products. These include online advertising technologies, search, cloud computing, software, and hardware. Google was founded in 1998 by Larry Page and Sergey Brin while they were Ph.D. students at Stanford University. Please call (123) 4444-3343

I want to make the number `(123) 4444-3343` to a clickable one and taps it will have the user go to the calling mode.

I have tried following code:

```
textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

It doesn't work at all. I only want the (123) 4444-3343 to be clickable. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*first* option u have is to add in your XML `android:autoLink="phone"` to your textView

the *second* option u have is to use Html.fromHtml

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("..." +
                "Please call <a href=\"tel:123-456-7890\">(123) 456-7890</a>"));
        txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        txt.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

*another* way is to use  **ClickableSpan** more info u can find here 
[How to set the part of the text view is clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html)

Comment: Yes, this wroks