# HTML text with onclicklistener

Tags: android, html, string, onclicklistener

I need to display a string programmatically in a textview with html formatting
eg. "find more information"+here" , where "here" can listen to onclick.
Is this possible or any other suggestions?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the part of the text view is clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SpannableString` with `ClickableSpan`.
Here is an example.

```
SpannableString span= new SpannableString("Find more information "+here"");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
@Override
public void onClick(View textView) {
    // Perform action here
}
@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    super.updateDrawState(ds);
    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
}
};
span.setSpan(clickableSpan, 23, 26, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(span);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```