# In Android, if I use binding, how to apply ClickableSpan?

Tags: android, spannablestring, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I know that if binding is not applied, then I can use `Textview.setText(ClickableSpan)` to apply spannig effect to make part of the text clickable. However, my app used binding and the textview's text is binded to a ViewModel inside xml like `android:text="@{model.certainString}"` and in the ViewModel I declared `String certainString = ""`, in this case how do I apply spanning inside the ViewModel then?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own BindingAdapter which accepts either the model or the string value, within the Adapter code you would then be able to apply a Spannable.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html