# Dividing the texts on Textview

Tags: java, android, textview, jsoup

Dividing the texts on Textview in order to be opened in a different modal when clicking on individual sentences.

Etc: according to full stop.

Text in Textview was pulled over via jsoup. I draw data with jsoup and I combine the texts into paragraphs. I want information about that statement to be printed when every sentence is printed. The application is written in java, android studio environment.

Etc article: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ut dui a velit bibendum tincidunt ac non eros. Maecenas vel risus molestie, ultrices turpis quis, mattis lorem. Suspendisse quis ultrices sem.

Separate clicks for all text:

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
- Duis ut dui a velit bibendum tincidunt ac non eros.
- Maecenas vel risus molestie, ultrices turpis quis, mattis lorem.
- Suspendisse quis ultrices sem.

Comment: Have you tryed replacing `.` by `.\r\n`?

Comment: The text needs to be in paragraph format. This is an article. My purpose is not to show it in the form of separate cues. My purpose is to connect each event separately to each event

Comment: You can use `SpannableString` please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable/10697453?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Worked ! Thank you.