# How can we set clickable for all of my word in a textview?

Tags: java, android

I want to set **clickable** for all of my **word** , Not special word . My app is a kind of Ebook that I want to set method `onclick` for them , Like translate.

Comment: Do you use a TextView?

Comment: Please elaborate your question with some code and detailed explanation.

Comment: Have a look at this : [Clickable Span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable)

Answer (score 0):

read official doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Text with clickable text");
string.setSpan(new CustomClickableSpan(), 10, 19,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Where "clickable" text is clickable

Comment: OK.  I know it . But I want every word can be clickable.  I mean , in your example : text , with , clickable and text . All of them . I want to make a story book and it's show translation by click on it .