# android click listener on an underlined part of a string

Tags: android

i have a signin screen, in multi-language app, in this screen we displpay errors that contains some actions(create account-reset password..etc), these action must be underlined and clickable. 
to achieve that, i set some part of strings as underlined with `<u></u>` tag.
and i set my text with:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(StringUtils.getLocalizedString.get(R.string.signin_error_404), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

but i don't know how to make this part of string clickable.

Answer (score -1):

use `ClickableSpan` this will make **clickable** word respond to click event

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tv_links);
final String login = getString(R.string.login);
final String register = getString(R.string.register);
String format = getString(R.string.title);
String title = String.format(format, login, register);

addLinksClickEvent(title, textView, new Pair(login, new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, login + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }), new Pair(register, new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, register + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }));
```

the method wchich do the clicks part which is inspired from one answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable) but in **java**

```
@SafeVarargs
public final void addLinksClickEvent(final String text, TextView textView, Pair<String, View.OnClickListener>... links) {
    final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    for (final Pair<String, View.OnClickListener> link : links) {
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
                Selection.setSelection((Spannable) ((TextView) view).getText(), 0);
                view.invalidate();
                link.second.onClick(view);
            }
        };
        int startIndexOfLink = text.indexOf(link.first);
        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + link.first.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

I use Arabic and English languages so

**values**

```
<string name="title">You can %1$s or if you donn\'t have account you can %2$s</string>
<string name="login">login</string>
<string name="register">register</string>
```

**values-ar**

```
<string name="login">تسجيل الدخول </string>
<string name="register">التسجيل </string>
<string name="title">يمكنك %1$s, اذا لما يكمن لديك حساب يمكنك %2$s من هنا</string>
```

Comment: Yes i know this approach!, but i want to use it, beaause we have multiple languages in our app, and i don't want to give the start and the end index in a explicit way.

Comment: you can get your current language words as string then use it's length instead of hard coding indexes I think it will work

Comment: (idont want**: correction of the first comment)
-i think that in all cases, i have to store the targetted sentence in a way to get the start and the end index later. 
if there is a way to extract just the text which is between <u></u> tag dynalically, it will be great to use it with ClickableSpan