# Hi,How I design the UI , I know use html code can make color different,but I need click part just only orange

Tags: android

[Just only orange part can click，so my code can't just use a Textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUueo.png)

How I design the UI, I know use Html code can make color different，but I need click part just only orange

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I hope this is what you searching for**

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
    String myString = "Some text [clickable]";
    int i1 = myString.indexOf("[");
    int i2 = myString.indexOf("]");
        myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        myTextView.setText(myString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        Spannable mySpannable = (Spannable)myTextView.getText();
        ClickableSpan myClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View widget) { /* do something */ }
        };
        mySpannable.setSpan(myClickableSpan, i1, i2 + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

If you need more Reference please follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable)

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to use a class named SpannableString. look here how to use it in kotlin - 
https://medium.com/@programmerr47/working-with-spans-in-android-ca4ab1327bc4